# Improper use of joins - how to rectify it

Tags: sql-server

I would like to understand why revenue.RevC and revenue.RevD appears as Null even though when I run the separate nested selected on another tab it brings information up.

Can you spot a mistake that I am doing with my joins that prevents me from getting any data in my [rev col] and [rev del] columns. I believe it is due to using the left joins. Am I correct?

```
 with CTE as 
 (
select count(tpt1.MovConID) as [Collections], 
count(tpt2.MovConID) as [Count of Del],
sum (c1.[Chargeable Weight]) as [Total Col Chg Wt],
sum(c2.[Chargeable Weight]) as [Total Del Chg Wt],
revenueC.RevC as [Rev Col],
revenueD.RevD as [Rev Del]
from tptvehicle tptv
left JOIN tptHeader tpth ON tpth.VehicleID = tptV.VehicleID
left JOIN tptVehicleRevenueDaily tptrevenue on tptrevenue.VehicleReg = tptv.RegNo
left Join (select tpth.RunReference, tptV.VehicleID, sum(tptvehicle.Amount) as RevC from tptVehicleRevenueDaily tptvehicle 
       inner join tptVehicle tptv on tptv.RegNo = tptvehicle.VehicleReg
       inner join tptHeader tptH on tptH.VehicleID = tptv.VehicleID
       inner join tptDetails tpt on tpt.RunID = tptH.RunID where tpt.RunType = 'C'
       group by tpth.RunReference, tptv.VehicleID) revenueC on revenueC.RunReference = Tpth.RunReference
Left Join (select tpth.RunReference, tptV.VehicleID, sum(tptvehicle.Amount) as RevD from tptVehicleRevenueDaily tptvehicle 
       inner join tptVehicle tptv on tptv.RegNo = tptvehicle.VehicleReg
       Inner join tptHeader tptH on tptH.VehicleID = tptv.VehicleID
       Inner join tptDetails tpt on tpt.RunID = tptH.RunID where tpt.RunType = 'D'
       group by tpth.RunReference, tptv.VehicleID) revenueD on revenueD.VehicleID = TptV.VehicleID
 LEFT JOIN tptDetails tpt1 ON tpt1.RunID = tptH.RunID and tpt1.RunType = 'C'
 LEFT JOIN cgtConsignment c1 on c1.[Consignment Reference] = tpt1.MovConID
 LEFT JOIN tptDetails tpt2 on tpt2.RunID = tptH.RunID and tpt2.RunType = 'D'
 LEFT Join cgtConsignment c2 on c2.[Consignment Reference] = tpt2.MovConID
 where tpth.RunReference like 'bham-%' and
 tptH.JourneyDate >= @StartDate and
          tpth.JourneyDate <= @EndDate 
          Group by revenueC.RevC, revenueD.RevD
 )
Select cte.collections, cte.[count of del], cte.[Total Col Chg Wt], cte.[Total Del Chg Wt], cte.[Rev Col], cte.[Rev Del]
from CTE
```

Comment: It is very likely a data problem.  `revenueC` and `revenueD` are joined through (left) outer joins which means that if their join conditions do not match, they will return a row of nulls instead.

Comment: tpth is LEFT JOINed, with WHERE clause against tpth, it becomes a INNER JOIN.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the entire contents of the CTE (i.e. the definition)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes a left join will show you rows from the left hand side of the join (tptvehicle, tptHeader and tptVehicleRevenueDaily) even if no rows exist in your nested query... If you change it to an inner join, it will show only rows where these exist, however this will EXCLUDE vehicles which have no rows in this nested query (which are currently showing with nulls in those columns), do you want this?...